# Read sqlite file with sqlite3 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

We have an iOS app that use sqlite files to store data locally.  We have a Rails app hosted at heroku that we'd like to post the sqlite files to, process the data, and insert records into our PG database.

Heroku does not allow sqlite at all, and we can not install the sqlite3 gem.  We only want to read the sqlite files, and don't need to use the sqlite as a db at heroku.

Is there a way to read sqlite files on heroku?

Comment: Do you really want to read an sqlite file without using sqlite?

Comment: Take a look ate this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of dumping data to a file and then reading this file? http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-dump-backup-database-file-how

Comment: The problem is that i can't dump the file on heroku.  I somehow need to read the file on heroku after a user submits it.

Comment: I posted an answer talking about this. If you want to keep reading this sqlite3 database over and over, this is not a good idea. My answer explains why. And no, you won't dump your database at Heroku. You must dump it `at your development enviroment` and then push the results to Heroku. You won't have so much freedom at Heroku and God knows they are right in doing so. Can you imagine the safety nightmare it would be with thousands of users doing anything they want?

Answer (score 0):

I see three possibilities:

1) You may dump your sqlite3 database to a  file and then import the contents to a PostgreSQL database at Heroku. You may dump it following the instructions [here](http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-dump-backup-database-file-how). To import you may write a rake task or run a program to perform this task at command line. You may even use db/seeds.rb to perform this task.

2) You may dump your sqlite3 database to a file and try to make PostgreSQL import data directly from this file. I've never tried that and you'll probably find some issues. Output formats are sometimes a bit different when you move from one database to another. Databases are seldom "100%-pure-SQL-compliant".

**IMPORTANT**: In both cases you'll dump **in your development environment** and then push the results to Heroku.

3) You may write a program to "understand" sqlite database's format. This would imply in rewriting sqlite and you must check if you really want to put yourself in so much trouble. Even you consider this task is worth the time and effort you'll dedicate to it, consider also what Heroku says [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) about storing files in their filesystem. This is the important message:

```
SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk.
While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack has
an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read from it,
but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to use SQLite
on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least once every
24 hours.
```

I also suggest you to take a look at this article [here](http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/02/i-want-to-use-heroku-but-my-app-uses.html). It may help you to save some time and effort next time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up hosting a rails app on another vps and processing the sqlite files there, then sending JSON over to my main heroku app, that we then added records to the postgresql db.  Thanks.

Comment: Great that you solved it. And sorry for not being helpful.